# How to build clang for x86_64 so that Asan AArch64 libraries are available?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, arm64

I'm trying to build LLVM (clang-16.0.5) to run on x86_64 Linux and be able to build arm64 programs with Asan. Nothing I'm doing is building any libs for other than x86(_64). I'm currently invoking cmake with this:

```
...
cmake \
    -G "CodeBlocks - Ninja" \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${var1} \
    ${var2}/source/llvm \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${var3} \
    -DLLVM_PARALLEL_LINK_JOBS=1 \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS='clang;clang-tools-extra;lldb;compiler-rt;lld;polly' \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES=all \
    -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=all \
    "$@"
...
```

Is there some other way I should be invoking cmake? I tried setting `-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD='X86;AArch64'` and got the same result, no arm64 libs.